# Reading files by power query differs between Excel files

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a folder with many Excel files. The files are structured in the same format so the first column supposed to be empty . The problem is that in some of the files the query manages to understand that the first column is empty, and displays the second column (the first with the data) as the first column. While in other files he displays the blank column - as the first column and writes `null` inside.

This creates a mess when you combine the files together.
Is there a way for the query to ignore the first column in excel files no matter what it contains?

```
let Source = 
Folder.Files(""),
#"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
#"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
#"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type any}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type any}, {"Column11", type text}, {"Column12", type any}, {"Column13", type any}, {"Column14", type any}, {"Column15", type any}, {"Column16", type any}, {"Column17", type any}, {"Column18", type any}, {"Column19", type any}, {"Column20", type any}}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "שם המנפיק/שם נייר ערך"}, {"Column2", "מספר ני""ע"}, {"Column3", "זירת מסחר"}, {"Column4", "ספק מידע"}, {"Column5", "מספר מנפיק"}, {"Column6", "ענף מסחר"}, {"Column7", "דירוג"}, {"Column8", "שם מדרג"}, {"Column9", "תאריך רכישה"}, {"Column10", "מח""מ"}, {"Column11", "סוג מטבע"}, {"Column12", "שיעור ריבית"}, {"Column13", "תשואה לפידיון"}, {"Column14", "ערך נקוב"}, {"Column15", "שער"}, {"Column16", "פדיון/ ריבית לקבל"}, {"Column17", "שווי שוק"}, {"Column18", "שעור מערך נקוב מונפק"}, {"Column19", "שעור מנכסי אפיק ההשקעה"}, {"Column20", "שעור מסך נכסי השקעה"}}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"מח""מ", type number}, {"שיעור ריבית", Percentage.Type}, {"תשואה לפידיון", Percentage.Type}, {"ערך נקוב", type number}, {"שער", type number}, {"פדיון/ ריבית לקבל", type number}, {"שווי שוק", type number}, {"שעור מערך נקוב מונפק", Percentage.Type}, {"שעור מנכסי אפיק ההשקעה", Percentage.Type}, {"שעור מסך נכסי השקעה", Percentage.Type}}),
#"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"שם המנפיק/שם נייר ערך", "שם ני""ע"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns2", "Custom", each "אגרות חוב קונצרניות"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each true),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"סוג מטבע", type text}}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type2", each true)
in #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: Please edit your post and paste a copy of your code from home...advanced editor... assuming it is in PowerQuery

Comment: done. 
This is the code of the specific problematic query